# DRY zf2 Module.php

Tags: zend-framework2, dry

Is there a standard way to DRY Module.php? I have several simple Module.php files like this

```
<?php
namespace SolImporter;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

Only the namespace is different and of course PHPCPD complains about this.

Comment: The Problem is that we require the constants of `__DIR__` inside those functions. If it weren't for those you would be able to use a `trait` for that. But when using `__DIR__` inside a `trait` it will return the directory of the `trait` rather than the directory of the class that uses the `trait`. So in short: i don't think there's a way to dry this up :S

Comment: For now I've excluded the Module.php from the phpcpd checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. However, you create another dependency which is not really needed for the Module. And furthermore, you cannot get the `__DIR__` of your child class without reflection. And reflection can harm your performance, especially if you use this for every module class (and every module class is, by its principle, loaded on every request).

But here it goes:

```
namespace MyCommon\Module;

class AbstractModule
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        $dir       = $this->getDir();
        $namespace = $this->getNamespace();

        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    $namespace => $dir . '/src/' . $namespace,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $dir = $this->getDir();

        return include $dir . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    protected function getDir()
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        return dirname($reflection->getFileName());
    }

    protected function getNamespace()
    {
        return str_replace('\Module', '', get_class($this));
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
namespace MyModule;

use MyCommon\Module\AbstractModule;

class Module extends AbstractModule
{
}
```